# Pinpointing cause of slow WCF self-hosted service in certain environments

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to debug why our software (client and server) is slow in certain environments. I've tried a few things without success and now I'm at a loss for how to continue tracking down the issue. My question is: what are some things I can try or look into to resolve this issue?

We are developing a WCF self-hosted service to be run on a server, and a client application to connect to it. The service interacts with a database (MS SQL server).

Setup A

- Server is running in VM (2 GB RAM, 1 core for the VM)
- client is separate desktop machine on same intranet
- Client startup (authentication and init -- about 40 service calls) is done in less than five seconds

Setup B

- Server is not virtualized (16 GB RAM, dual XEON e5-2640)
- Client is running on same machine as server (connect to 127.0.0.1) for test purposes
- Client startup takes about 45 seconds

Similarities

- Server and client software are same version for both setups
- Server operating system is windows 2008 r2
- Windows role of file server and IIS (there shouldn't be any other server-type activities going on except for SQL server)
- Windows feature of .NET 4.5.1

Differences

- Setup B is using SQL server 2012. Setup A is using SQL server 2008
- Setup A and B are over 1000 miles apart (different networks, managed under different IA rules)
- Some differences in windows server features, but nothing that *looks* like it should cause a problem

Things I've tried

- Setup A has no firewall and no antivirus on the server.
- Setup B has windows firewall disabled. Symantic endpoint protection is running; insight, bloodhound, auto-protect, download insight were disabled for testing but made no difference.
- SQL integration, reporting and analysis services were disabled with little change.
- I've looked in windows event viewer and don't see anything out of the ordinary, but I'm not sure if there's something specific I should be looking for.
- I've enabled WCF logging (as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6100339)), but looking at the log in SvcTraceViewer.exe isn't really telling me anything useful.
- Likewise, attempting to log various stats in perfmon has not been productive.

Other thoughts

- Not using Entity Framework in the service.
- file storage is on the same physical machine
- Server is running IIS for a related webtool, but the WCF self-hosted service should be unaffected (right?)
- Running SQL profiler, all of the database calls are resolving quickly (milliseconds) so I don't think it's a database issue.
- CPU use is always very low. RAM usage on setup B is less than 60% (per task manager).
- Since it doesn't seem to be a database or resource issue, I'm guessing it's a networking or WCF issue.

Things I'm going to try next

- There are a few differences still left to resolve -- different patches, server features, etc
- Clone setup A VM onto setup B server
- not sure

Service app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <configSections>
      <section name="fooNET.serviceProvider" type="foo.fooNET.ServiceRegistration.Classes.ServiceProviderConfiguration, foo.fooNET.ServiceRegistration" />
      <section name="nlog" type="bar.com.foo.NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, foo.NLog" />
   </configSections>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="BaseDB" connectionString="..." />
      <add name="UserStore2" connectionString="..." />
      <add name="UserStore" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
      <add name="MetricCollectionDAL.Properties.Settings.MASSMetricsConnectionString" connectionString="..." />
   </connectionStrings>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="maxRequestLength" value="16384" />
      <add key="exclusiveFlag" value="true" />
      <add key="SubscriptionDeleteNotification" value="true" />
   </appSettings>
   <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <targets>
         <target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/fooNetLog.txt" keepFileOpen="true" layout="${date:format=MM/dd/yyyy HH\:mm\:ss}|${level}|${windows-identity}|${callsite}|${message}" archiveEvery="Day" maxArchiveFiles="5" />
         <target name="session" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/sessionlog.txt" keepFileOpen="true" layout="${date:format=MM/dd/yyyy HH\:mm\:ss}|${level}|${windows-identity}|${callsite}|${message}" concurrentWrites="false" deleteOldFileOnStartup="true" />
      </targets>
      <rules>
         <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="file,session" />
      </rules>
   </nlog>
   <fooNET.serviceProvider xmlns="foo.fooNET">
      <plugins directory="Plugins" />
      <baseAddress uri="https://localhost:6040/ServiceProvider" />
      <brokers count="1" remoteRegister="true" registrationInterval="1" />
   </fooNET.serviceProvider>
   <system.serviceModel>
      <diagnostics performanceCounters="All" />
      <services>
         <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceProviderBehavior" name="foo.fooNET.ServiceRegistration.Classes.ServiceProvider">
            <endpoint address="" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ws2007Binding" behaviorConfiguration="EndpointBehavior" contract="foo.fooNET.Shared.Server.Interfaces.IServiceProvider" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
               <baseAddresses>
                  <add baseAddress="https://localhost:6040/ServiceProvider" />
               </baseAddresses>
               <timeouts closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" />
            </host>
         </service>
      </services>
      <behaviors>
         <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceProviderBehavior">
               <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" policyVersion="Policy15" />
               <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
               <serviceSecurityAudit auditLogLocation="Application" suppressAuditFailure="false" serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="Failure" messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="Failure" />
               <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="32" maxConcurrentSessions="20" maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" />
            </behavior>
         </serviceBehaviors>
         <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="EndpointBehavior">
               <dispatcherSynchronization maxPendingReceives="6" />
            </behavior>
         </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
      <bindings>
         <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
            <binding name="2007MtomBinding" closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="00:40:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="00:40:00" transactionFlow="false" maxBufferPoolSize="0" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom" useDefaultWebProxy="false">
               <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
               <reliableSession ordered="false" inactivityTimeout="01:00:00" enabled="false" />
               <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                  <message establishSecurityContext="false">
                     <claimTypeRequirements>
                        <add claimType="http://bar.com/foo/fooNET/claims/FirstName" isOptional="false" />
                     </claimTypeRequirements>
                  </message>
               </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="ws2007Binding" closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="00:40:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="0" useDefaultWebProxy="false">
               <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
               <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="01:00:00" />
               <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                  <message negotiateServiceCredential="false" establishSecurityContext="false">
                     <claimTypeRequirements>
                        <add claimType="http://bar.com/foo/fooNET/claims/FirstName" isOptional="false" />
                     </claimTypeRequirements>
                  </message>
               </security>
            </binding>
         </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
         <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="AuthenticationBinding" closeTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="00:40:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" bypassProxyOnLocal="true">
               <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
               <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="01:00:00" />
               <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
         </wsHttpBinding>
         <ws2007HttpBinding>
            <binding name="SecurityAuth" sendTimeout="00:40:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" useDefaultWebProxy="false">
               <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
               <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="01:00:00" />
               <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                  <message negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
               </security>
            </binding>
         </ws2007HttpBinding>
      </bindings>
   </system.serviceModel>
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

Update 2014-11-18

Received a "snapshot" of server A (single file.vhd). Created a new VM in hyper-v (had to add hyper-v role) on Server B with single CPU and 2 GB RAM and loaded in server A vhd. Local VM of server A with localhost connection is just as fast as expected. The only thing this tells me is there's nothing wrong with the physical box. Tried changing the number of cores allocated to the VM to 4 with little to no change.

Comment: can you show what your .config file looks like .. I am interested in seeing what these 2 lines look like 
`<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>` and 
`<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>`

Comment: Might try Fiddler or Wire Shark to see if you can get network packet info and compare them. I assume same IIS version and the app pool is running the same .NET framework?

Comment: @dj-kraze posted service app.config

Comment: @steve both are running IIS 7.5, but a self-hosted WCF service shouldn't be running on IIS right?

Comment: @Steve Using Wireshark on server B will not be easy, since this is a localhost connection which requires special configuration to be visible to Wireshark,which I have never managed to get working. But you could connect client A to server B... Use of Fiddler requires that the client can be told to use an HTTP proxy (in this case Fiddler).

Comment: Which editions of SQL Server are you using? You have to keep in mind that some editions (Express is obviously the worst offender here) are limited in terms of processor affinity and max memory. Also: have you done any benchmarking in terms of IO (disks)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stood up the Server A VM. I made three changes

1. IP address to be visible on the network
2. Joined the local domain
3. Changed service account from [previous] domain to local computer (not domain) account

I ran wireshark and captured the initial authentication and startup. Instantly got a ton of entries like the following:

[image]

I changed the account that runs the service to an account on the domain, but then I couldn’t communicate at all. I get an exception (on the client) which says

> “The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.”

Which seems to indicate there’s an uncaught/unhandled exception.

Managed to pull out a more helpful exception:

> “Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) authentication failed. The server may not 
>   be running in an account with identity 'host/[computer]'. If the server is running in a 
>   service account (Network Service for example), specify the account's 
>   ServicePrincipalName as the identity in the EndpointAddress for the server. If the server 
>   is running in a user account, specify the account's UserPrincipalName as the identity 
>   in the EndpointAddress for the server.”

Was about to start trying to figure out what that means (e.g. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628618.aspx)), but then I changed from domain account to “local system account” checkbox in the services.msc and everything is super speedy.